# How to get a substring from a string

Tags: java, string, substring

I have this xml file from where I'm reading this string,

```
http://localhost:8080/sdpapi/request/10/notes/611/
```

My question is how can I get just the 611, which is of variable, can be 100000, for example, from this string?

Comment: Questions lacks basic research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string

```
String input = "http://localhost:8080/sdpapi/request/10/notes/611/";

String output = input.split("notes/")[1].split("/")[0];
```

**output** is the value you need

Answer (score 0):

well, it depend in what language are you writing... in c# for example

```
string s = @"http://localhost:8080/sdpapi/request/10/notes/611/";
s.SubString(s.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

or

```
Path.GetFileName(s);
```

for java

```
new File(s).getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

What language?

Anyway, in most cases it's a syntax like:

```
String.substring(begin, length);
```

... where 'begin' is the number of the letter in the string-1. For extracting http from the above string you would write

```
substring(0, 4);
```

In case you always need the last string between the last two '/'s, you can retrieve the position of the slashes with index-functions (as stated in the answer of @Liran for example).

// EDIT: In Java the second parameter of substring is not length, but endIndex:

```
String s = "http://localhost:8080/sdpapi/request/10/notes/611/";
s.substring(46, s.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: That's fine, but I don't think that using "magic" values is ok (46).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on programming language you use, but Regular Expressions should be the same in most of them:

```
/(\d+)\/$/
```